# Why cannot access my site neither localy or with the domain name using Apache2 as a web Server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I just can access my site using the ip-address of my ubuntu server. I tried using domain name *test_sites.com* (in a browser as `http://test_sites.com`) or via localhost/127.0.0.1 (want access just localy), but I am getting **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**!
This is my conf-file *test_sites.com.conf* (very simple):

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

`ServerName test_sites.com`

`ServerAlias www.test_sites.com`

`DocumentRoot /var/www/test_sites.com`

`here logLevel`

`</VirtualHost>`

> So I put `127.0.0.1 test_sites.com` in the `hosts`-file in windows

> I disabled the firewall in windows and the firewall `ufw` in ubuntu

> I put `ServerName localhost:80` in addition to `listen 80` in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

> I edited the `hosts`-file in Ubuntu:

````
  ```127.0.0.1 localhost```
 
  ```127.0.0.1 test_sites.com```

  ```my-ip-addr test_sites.com```
````

But unfortunately the connection still:  **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

When I `curl test_sites.com` *or* `curl http://tets_sites.com` I get back the contents of `index.html`

What am I doing wrong? Any help/tips is very appreciated!

Comment: You're using an *underscore* in your domain? Domains may contain dashes, but not underscores. Have you confirmed that other domain names are similarly rejected?

Comment: @matigo (thanks) - I changed ```test_sites.com``` to ```testsite-localy.com```, but I still getting *ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* even if I put ``` 127.0.0.1 testsite-localy.com``` in ```hosts```-file in windows!! - I don't understand why apache2  cannot serve my site localy using a domain name (it goes well when I try with ip-addr of ubu-serv)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ufw` is allowing the traffic through? Have you also confirmed that the browser is using `http` rather than `https`, which many default to? 

Comment: I disabled ```https``` in my browsers (firefox & Micosoft edge) and I allowed traffic with ```ufw```: ````sudo ufw status``` and I get: ```Apache Full``` action ```ALLOW``` From ```Anywhere``` and ```Apache Full (v6)``` ... still same pbm!

Comment: does all of this happen on a single computer - the running apache, testing with curl and access with firefox/edge?

Comment: @dummyuser - my apache is running on an ubuntu server and I am trying access the site from a single windows computer.

Comment: ok, your windows server is not able to resolve names which are defined in the hostfile of your linux server. And a server will **never** be able to access a `127.0.0.1` on a different host. edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the `testsite-localy.com` with the external IP of your linux server (not `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: I guess even a ping from the windows server to `testsite-localy.com` does not work.

Comment: @dummyuser - BINGO! - Now I understand my mistakes. Can you make it as an answer and I will accept it with maaaany thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, your windows server is not able to resolve names which are defined in the host file of your linux server. And a server will never be able to access a `127.0.0.1` on a different host. edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the testsite-localy.com with the external IP of your linux server (not `127.0.0.1`)

Name service resolution must happen on the client, never on the server. You may setup a DNS Service centrally, but this is a separate project :-).

Comment: What do you mean to setup a DNS Service centrally?

Comment: Editing hosfilesit is a bad idea. Name resolution should be done by the DNS Service. this may happen with a domain owned by you in the internet or a kind of a private DNS server.